# How can I rewrite the python code without using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to 'translate' a code which used the module pandas into a code not using pandas.

the code looks like this:

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXP7P.png)

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv('review.csv')
data
titles=data['book_title']
temp=[]
for name in titles:
    temp.append(name)
temp_set=set(temp)
temp_list=list(temp_set)
temp_list
data_simple=data.filter(items=['book_title','stars_given'])
data_simple=data_simple.set_index('book_title')
result_table=[]
for title in temp_list:
  book_data=data_simple.filter(like=title,axis=0)
  average=book_data['stars_given'].mean()
   result_table.append([title,average])
result=pd.DataFrame(data=result_table, columns=['book_title', 'average_rating'])
result
result.to_csv('average_rating.csv', index=False, encoding='cp949')
```

(check out the picture; my typing may not be accurate)

Not using the pandas module and only using the built-in modules, (such as beginning with 'import csv') can somebody please help changing the codes?

Comment: One question. Why?!

Comment: @Nohman actually this is for my school project, and the professor banned us from using pandas...

Comment: @Nohman I could write a code using pandas, and all I have to do now is change the codes

Comment: Ouch. Well you can use the csv module https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: @Nohman I've tried, but I could never figure out the right codes to replace '.filter' or '.DataFrame'.

Comment: instead of filter, you can use for loop with conditions. So solving it with pure python function. When you need help, you can ask again here with more details of your code and what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I suggest to start with `f = open('review.csv'); headers = f.readline()[:-1].split(','); title_index = headers.index('book_title'); ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest using:

- CSV Module
- List comprehension for filtering data

**Code**

```
import csv

# Load Data
with open('review.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    data = []
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    
    for row in csv_reader:
        data.append(row)  # each row is a dictionary containing
                          # column names as keys
                          # and data in CSV file row as values

print(data)

# Names of unique book titles
temp = []
for name in [row['book_title'] for row in data]: # list comprehension for titles column
    temp.append(name)
temp_set = set(temp)
temp_list=list(temp_set)
print(temp_list)

# Filter to book_titles and stars_given 
# Each row is a dictioanry, using dictionary comprehension
data_simple = [{column:row[column] for column in ['book_title', 'stars_given']} for row in data]
print(data_simple)
   
# Mean of stars by title
# Dictionary to look up column indexes for book_title and stars_given
result_table = []
for title in temp_list:
    # Filter to rows with title
    book_data = [row for row in data_simple if row['book_title']==title]
    
    # Sum up number of stars for book
    sum_ = sum(int(row['stars_given']) for row in book_data)
    average = sum_ / len(book_data)
    result_table.append((title, average))   # store each as tuple
    
print(result_table)

# Create resulting CSV
with open('average_rating.csv', 'w', newline = '', encoding = 'cp949') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    csv_writer.writerow(['book_title', 'average_rating'])  # Header
    for row in result_table:
        csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

**Test**

*File: review.csv*

```
book_title,stars_given,comment
abc,5,loved it
def,3,okay to watch
bce,2,too long
abc,4,very funny
```

*File: average_rating.csv*

```
book_title,average_rating
def,3.0
abc,4.5
bce,2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think NumPy could make it?

```
 import numpy as np
  
# using loadtxt()
arr = np.loadtxt("review.csv",
                 delimiter=",", dtype=str)
```

I am not sure but try Numpy.